# Why hardware virtualization feature of x86 CPU can only be enabled in BIOS?

Tags: x86

I noticed that x86 hardware virtualization features like VT-x and AMD-V/svm can only be enabled via BIOS configuration menu. I have two questions regarding this.

1. Why these hardware virtualization features can only be enabled in BIOS? Why can't OS bypass the BIOS and enable these features directly (by setting a few bits in control registers I think)?
2. Why bother to switch these virtualization features on and off, why not just let it be enabled? Is it because there are some performance or power consumption penalty even if you don't use it?

Comment: For security reasons mostly:
1. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15555/can-a-hypervisor-rootkit-enable-hardware-assisted-virtualization-when-it-has-bee
2. http://serverfault.com/questions/390012/why-do-systems-generally-disable-virtualization-by-default-in-bios-settings

Comment: I believe there's some feature bit that, once disabled (by BIOS or otherwise), cannot be re-enabled until reboot

Answer (score 0):

I wish people would post answers, even if they're short.

When the system boots up, everything is enabled.  The BIOS can *disable* features, and once disabled they are not enableable until the next reboot.  So your confusion is from misunderstanding what the BIOS is offering.  It's not so much offering you the feature of enabling stuff, it's offering you the feature of *disabling* stuff.  This is why the OS can't just enable it later.

And as jaroslawj points out, it's for security reasons.  If you're not using virtualization, you don't want a rootkit to set itself up as a hypervisor, because that would let it hide from antivirus tools extremely well.  (This is also why you want the BIOS disabling these features, instead of waiting until after booting potentially compromised disks.)